# How to separate a vector through ifelse and labels?

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a `chisq.test` to a week of criminal statistics. In the
first ChiSquare test I realized that the days are not equally distributed.

**First Chisq.test**

```
DAYS = c("So"=53, "Mo"=42, "Di"=51, "Mi"=45, "Do"=36, "Fr"=37, "Sa"=65)
DAYS

So Mo Di Mi Do Fr Sa 
53 42 51 45 36 37 65 

chisq.test(DAYS)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

        data:  DAYS
        X-squared = 13.3191, df = 6, p-value = 0.03824
```

As a next question I want to check the expected distribution of weekdays(Monday to Friday) and the weekend (Saturday + Sunday). I tried to divide it with an `ifelse` statement into the group weekend and weekdays. However, the resulting `week` variable only contains `weekday` and `weekend`.

**How can I divide the array by the labels to achieve something like below?**

A wished output would be like

```
week
weekend weekday
118     211
```

**How I tried to separate it**

```
week <- ifelse(DAYS %in% c("So", "Sa"), "weekend", "workday")

week
"workday" "workday" "workday" "workday" "workday" "workday"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
week <- ifelse(names(DAYS) %in% c("So", "Sa"), "weekend", "workday")
week
[1] "weekend" "workday" "workday" "workday" "workday" "workday" "weekend"
```

And then

```
DAYS_df <- data.frame(DAYS)
DAYS_df$week <- as.factor(ifelse(names(DAYS) %in% c("So", "Sa"), "weekend", "workday"))
by(DAYS_df$DAYS, DAYS_df$week, sum)
DAYS_df$week: weekend
[1] 118
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DAYS_df$week: workday
[1] 211
```